# `socat` does not always kill the child process

Tags: socat

I have a `socat` that spawns an `ssh` command:

```
socat "tcp-listen:${local_port},reuseaddr,fork,bind=127.0.0.1,keepalive,keepidle=10,keepintvl=10,keepcnt=2" "system:ssh -t -e none -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o LogLevel=ERROR ${user}@${host} <some command>
```

Sometimes it will happen that killing the `socat` process does not kill the `ssh` process. Is there a flag that I'm missing?